# Can we create backup of a stored procedure like we do for backup of a table?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

This is the syntax for create backup of a table :

`create table xyz_new as select * from xyz;`

Like wise do we have any way to create backup for a stored procedure in oracle sql ?

If we possible can we implement it in python `cx_Oracle` .

Comment: What kind of backup do you except - backup it for example in different schema compiled, or backup the DDL of the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user_source` data dictionary view as :

```
import cx_Oracle

con = cx_Oracle.connect('<un>/<pwd>@<host>:<port>/<service_name>')
c = con.cursor()

v_sql  = "create table t_my_proc as "
v_sql += "select s.text "
v_sql += "  from user_source s "
v_sql += "where s.name = upper('my_proc') "
c.execute(v_sql)
```

when you run the above code a table with name `t_my_proc` is created within your user `<un>`